# Deploy JMS Query using Arquillian

Tags: maven, jms, jboss-arquillian

I'm using arquilian to test a JMS query. I've seen that i'm able to deploy a descriptor using the `Descriptors` class, like below:

```
@Deployment
 public static Descriptor create() {
      return Descriptors.create(HornetQDescriptor.class);
 }
```

Ok, but I can't find the HornetQDescriptor class anywhere! I'm using Arquillian 1.1.7.Final, with ShrinkWrap Desriptors 2.0.0-Alpha-7 and Maven. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a trick...

I added a `hornetq-jms.xml` to `src/test/resources` and to my arquillian jar and it worked fine. It was something like that:

```
@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
        .addAsManifestResource("hornetq-jms.xml")
        .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));
}
```

and one default hornetq xml:

```
<messaging-deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:messaging-deployment:1.0">
    <hornetq-server>
        <jms-destinations>
            <jms-queue name="myQueue">
                <entry name="/queue/myQueue"/>
            </jms-queue>
        </jms-destinations>
    </hornetq-server>
</messaging-deployment>
```

And it worked fine. Not the way I expected doing, but it worked anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of server u used , embedded or managed . 
I am tryin to use hornetq-jms.xml  but the embedded server I use is throwing exception about the xmlns="urn:jboss:messaging-deployment:1.0" .

About the HornetQDescriptor there are examples from 2011's versio of the descriptor api : [Check this git hub location](https://github.com/wolfc/descriptors-hornetq)

As far the Api is changed for example : Descriptor Api 
org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors » shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee » 2.0.0-alpha-9

The api is totally changed so the code above is not usable  am afraid .

So can u give me more details what server u used and if it is embedded how u suceed to deploy the hornet - jms . xml

Comment: Hello, I probably (it was some time ago) used JBoss managed, since you need to use the Full configuration file for the messaging API to work. Maybe if you use the embedded you need to point the full configuration file, and I'm not sure how to achieve it.